# anchor tag assigned span tag inner html

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have dynamically assigned anchor tag between span tag using javascript.

But anchor tag href formed incorrectly.

javascript

```
var HF1Id , HF2Id , SpanId ,
HF1Id = '<%=Request("HF1Id") %>' ;
HF2Id = '<%=Request("HF2Id") %>' ;
SpanId = '<%=Request("SpanId")  %>';

var a = "<a id=''anc''  href=''javascript:void(0)'' tabindex=''-1'' alt=''Download''";
a = a + " onclick=''javascript:ExpDownloadFile(" +  Some Text Here + ")''>View</a>";

alert(a);

opener.document.getElementById('<%=Request("SpanId")%>').innerHTML = String(a);

alert(opener.document.getElementById('<%=Request("SpanId")%>').innerHTML);
```

First Alert Shows correct order as per given.

But second alert shows incorrectly order.

Comment: Please can you provide the output of the two alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the output being passed through `innerHTML` should be html, however you are converting it to a string with `String(a);`

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp):

`The String() function converts the value of an object to a string.`

Also your string should use only single apostrophes as the are surrounding the text with double quotes meaning the apostrophes don't need to be escaped.

`"<a id='anc'  href='javascript:void(0)' tabindex='-1' alt='Download'"`

Comment: When removing one apostrophes it works fine.. Thanks